# How do you deploy an IIS Web App as a folder instead of a virtual application in Azure Devops pipeline?

Tags: iis, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have a release pipeline that publishes Virtual Applications from zip-files fine.

However we have some artifacts that we would like to be just a folder and not an application.

Is it possible to define that it should be deployed as a folder somewhere?
We are using the IIS Web App deploy task.

Comment: You can just copy the folder to your  application folder

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk It is not that easy. First the file needs to be extracted from the zip and placed somewhere. Then the files are deep in the extracted folder with a path that can change. Have tried doing that way but didn't manage to get a solution.

Comment: When you are deploying you may use the predefined variables, use a task to unzip your artifact, then using the predefined variables you may access any folder. 
As you say your folder will change but I don't think any project tree such change that much. If that is the case you might search for you a looking for and the copy to the designated IIS folder